# RAILS: skip if record exists otherwise save

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My **GOAL** is to `skip records that already exist in the database but save new records`.

I have a **composite unique key** as follows (in the migration):

```
add_index :table_name, [:feature1, :feature2], unique: true, name: 'idx_name'
```

I expect rails to use this index when checking for uniqueness.

In the model, I have tried the following:

```
records.each do |record|
  unless record.persisted?
    record.save!
  end
end
```

But I still get:

```
PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "idx_name"
```

How do I achieve my GOAL?

P.S. I have tried the following (as a sort of black magic for me... sorry for that):
`validates_uniqueness_of :idx_name, scope: [:my_table]` and `on_duplicate_key_update :idx_name` (I think that this does not do what I want

Thank you!

Comment: I'd suggest you do this from wherever you're creating the record, with something like `record = Model.where(feature1: x, feature2: y).first_or_create!`, and then rely on your index to fully enforce data integrity (since fyi, `first_or_create!` can still allow for race conditions).

Comment: @RobertNubel. Thank you. In the `parse` method I change the `record << Model.new(...)` to `Model.where(..).first_or_create!`  and then in method `db_update` I do `records.each(&:save!)` But I still get the error...

Comment: @RobertNubel. `save` was not needed and in fact was causing the trouble. It seems to be working good. THank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Exceptions, Catch, and Throw](https://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_exceptions.html)

```rb
records.each do |record|
 begin
   record.save!
 rescue PG::UniqueViolation
   next
 end
end
```